# Invisible Location History

Tags: google-maps, google-location-history

Location History was active on my device and visible under timeline in the Google Maps app. I have just tried to use it via Google maps on browser to get my phone back, but the timeline stops in August.

The Android Device Manager last located my phone just before 6am yesterday morning, so it was definitely communicating with my account.

Has anyone successfully made their Timeline visible on GMaps retroactively if Location History was on and able to communicate with the Google servers?

Comment: Are you saying that timeline worked fine in your phone till now? Meaning did you open Google maps timeline since August, and you saw that it works?

Comment: A bochur - Yes, I have seen it in the Google maps app on my phone since August. And even now, I can see that my Location History is on. But I lost the phone, and Google Maps in a browser is showing nothing past August 13th.